# Angular loading files from backend using the wrong port

Tags: django, angular

My Angular frontend application is using default port 4200. My Django backend application is running on port 8000. Frontend can upload files and images to backend, a then get their links to show on page. Uploading is working fine, but then when I try to get images from backend, Angular is downloading them from frontend port 4200 and all views are breaking, because there is no such files on that path.
Briefly, I need file path in that way - http://localhost:8000/media/uploads/myfile, but I get http://localhost:4200/media/uploads/myfile.
I use proxy to get backend api:

```
{
  "/api": {
  "target": "http://localhost:8000",
  "secure": false
  }
}
```

I do not know where the problem may be.

Comment: Add another proxy rule for `/media`

Answer (score 1):

You should add another proxy rule to *proxy* the media requests to django.

```
{
  "/api": {
  "target": "http://localhost:8000",
  "secure": false
  }, 

  "/media": {
  "target": "http://localhost:8000",
  "secure": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change proxy.conf.json:

```
{
  "/api": {
  "target": "http://localhost:8000",
  "secure": false,
  "changeOrigin": true,
  "pathRewrite": {
    "^/api": "http://localhost:8000/api"
  }
}
```

}

Comment: How does this even help in redirecting `media` requests?

Comment: there is no need in redirect. With that config all works fine